# Syntax error at the end of a valid for loop: for _ in range(lines):

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
lines = int(input("How many lines of code would you like?")

for _ in range(lines):
  #do stuff
```

But for some reason, I'm getting a syntax error on the colon in the for loop? I've tried changing the '_' for an 'i', and putting different code at #do stuff, but nothing's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the first line

```
lines = int(input("How many lines of code would you like?"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it really was that simple. I can't mark this as the correct answer for another 10 minutes but this did work.

Comment: @verybadatpython You're welcome, I'm glad I helped

Comment: you have more than enough reputation to know that you shouldn't bother with an "answer" for things like this - you can point it out in a comment, then vote to close as typo

Comment: @RobinZigmond is that a problem? but thanks anyway I'll take it into consideration next time

Comment: Not a "problem" as such, but it doesn't really benefit Stack Overflow as the chance of someone having the same problem again, or finding this exact question if they do, is negligible. I do agree with helping people, so I do answer similar questions with a comment and don't downvote the question (sadly some regular users would do the latter), but putting this as an answer isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for the advice, I will do so in the future. :)